# Tiger Audit reports "File does not belong to any package" but it does

Tags: security

I have just installed Tiger on a notebook and it generated a report containing a huge amount of false positives in the following style:

```
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/bundle2.7' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/bundler2.7' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/c89-gcc' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/c99-gcc' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/claws-mail' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/dillo' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/dillo-install-hyphenation' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/erb2.7' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/gedit' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/gem' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/gem2.7' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/gencat' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/irb2.7' does not belong to any package.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin001w] File `/bin/make' does not belong to any package.

The list goes on for 1782 lines, but from the sample above I can easily tell that "claws-mail", "dillo", "gedit" and "make" belong to their respective packages: I myself installed them using synaptic or apt-get!
```

With such a number of false positives the whole report becomes useless, don't you think? How is the user supposed to spot one or more legit warnings in a set of 1782? Is there a way to fine tune this Tiger test to at least reduce the number of false positives to a humanly manageable size?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: I agree but you would need to ask the maintainer why it shows these messages. Might be a bug.